# How to remove/hide this overlay Icon in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends, nvidia-geforce-experience

[image: Picture of the top right of my screen that shows a floating microphone and refresh icon]

As you can see on the top right corner, there's a mic icon and a refresh icon.

It kinda blocks my sight to monitor the time while I play League of Legends.

Is it an NVIDIA overlay setting or what else?

**How do I remove this icon?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What is this?

Those icons are for [NVIDIA Shadowplay](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/geforce-experience/shadowplay/), a process that allows you to record your screen and audio while you game. These icons mean that you can save a portion of the previous amount of time you've played a game as a video. The microphone icon indicates that your microphone audio is being recorded.

#### How do I simply remove these overlays?

If you want to remove the status overlays while still keeping Shadowplay running, you can:

1. Run the "Geforce Experience" application.
2. Click the "Share" button, as shown in the following screenshot:

> [image: Share icon in Geforce Experience]

3. Click the cog wheels on the right side (the preferences menu), navigate to "HUD Layout" and click the "Off" button.

#### How do I turn this feature off entirely?

1. Run "Geforce Experience"
2. Click the "Share" button in the top right.
3. Click the "Instant Replay" button and click "Turn off"

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is indeed an Nvidia Geforce Experience overlay.  There is a helpful video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgDqH2jzcr8) on how to turn this off.

1. Open Nvidia Geforce Experience
2. Click the Settings Icon
3. Find the "In-Game Overlay" option, and disable it.